# creating a custom service on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, services

I am setting up an ap called scumblr (https://github.com/Netflix/Scumblr/wiki)

The final step calls for initiating the server using the following 3 commands:

```
    redis-server &
../.rbenv/shims/bundle exec sidekiq -l log/sidekiq.log &
../.rbenv/shims/bundle exec rails s &
```

However, I do not want these tied to my user session. I would like them to start with the server and stay on. I think a service account/registered service would be best for that? How would I go about accomplishing this?

Thank you..

Comment: I would just add those commands to /etc/rc.local

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu, the proper way to install a service/daemon is to add a file to /etc/init.d as described in https://askubuntu.com/questions/335242/how-to-install-an-init-d-script-in-ubuntu